# Standard plugin project of Eclipse Indigo 3.7 do not work on Aptana studio 3 (Windows platform)

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, aptana, aptana3, eclipse-indigo

As a developer,
I created a plugin project on Eclipse indigo 3.7 with the standard tamplate “Plugin with a view” by the wizard.
I export the plugin project to jar file by the standard export wizard.
Then I want test it on Aptana studio 3 ( Windows platform) so I put it in dropins folder. After lunched Aptana studio 3 I expected to find the view of the plugin on Windows > Show view -> Other> Simple category but I can’t find Simple category.
I performed the same test with the jar file in plugins folder, with the same wrong result.
With the following configuration I can find plugin’s view:

```
Eclipse Indigo 3.7 ( on Windows platform)
Eclipse Indigo 3.7 with aptana plugin (on Windows platform)
Eclipse indigo 3.7 (on Ubuntu 12.04)
Eclipse Indigo 3.7 with aptana plugin (on Ubuntu 12.04)
Aptana studio 3 ( on Ubuntu 12.04)
```

Only with Aptana studio 3 (on Windows) I can’t find the plugin.
Someone can help me?

Comment: What version of Aptana Studio do you have?

Answer (score 0):

Try launching the target eclipse platform with a `-clean` attribute. Also have a look at dependencies of your plugin and ensure that if there are versions mentioned along with your dependencies, they are available on the target platform (you may simply remove the versions if you want)